# Recursively enumerable sets in ZF

Tags: set-theory, computability

I read often  definition of recursively enumerable set based on the concept of recursive function from N to the set, based on Turing machine, or on Levy hierarchy. How can i define recursively enumerable set only in the language of ZF without metalanguage's tricks? I would have a formula of ZF wich says 'x is recursively enumerable'. The class of r.e sets is transitive? If it is  not, how can express 'x is hereditary r.e' in ZF language?

Comment: What metalanguage tricks?  Why do you think it is difficult to specify notions like "recursive function" or "Turing machine" within ZF?

Comment: I didnt say it is difficult, just i cant do this end i m curious to know how to do it.

Comment: What approaches have you tried? We need to know what difficulties you are experiencing in order to help you.

Comment: I thought to consider Church Kleene ordinal and to stop the construction of L at this step. The problem is that dont know again how to say that Church Kleene ordinal is the first not r.e ordinal

Comment: The definition of turing machine and a computation of such can be given purely in terms of sets. You can find this already on wikipedia. So what is your question?

Comment: You should not be in need of using infinite oridinals (other than $\omega$) to talk about turing machines.

Comment: As an alternative to M. Winter's suggestions, the set of partial recursive functions is the smallest set of functions $\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$  that includes the constant 0 function, the successor function and is closed under ...: This set is easy to express in ZF as an intersection. What is your problem with this?

Comment: I know it , my difficult was to say not only that a subset of N is r.e, but a generic set. The initial functions have as imagine only natural numbers.

Comment: There is a standard notion of primitive recursive set function that goes back to a paper by Jensen and Karp. There are also various suggestions for the general notion of recursive set function, typically related to some higher order or transfinite model of computation.  There is also a well-established field of higher recursion theory. Sacks has an excellent book on the matter. Is this the sort of thing you are after? R.e. sets and the like can then be defined in terms of the generalized notions.

Comment: Thanks Andrès!! It ia exactly what i was looking for. I will check your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A notion now considered standard of primitive recursive set function is introduced in

> [MR0281602 (43 #7317)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=281602). Jensen, Ronald B.; Karp, Carol. *Primitive recursive set functions*. In **1971 Axiomatic Set Thoory** (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Vol. XIII, Part I, Univ. California, Los Angeles, Calif., 1967) pp. 143–176 Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I.

The concept is useful when dealing with arguments that require verifying absoluteness of certain notions, typically in contexts where one only has access to limited resources (for instance, working in admissible sets; Jensen also uses it in some fine-structural arguments, particularly by considering properties of primitive recursive ordinals). As with the classical notion, one can characterize the functions in terms of complexity of definitions, see

> [MR1187458 (94b:03090)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1187458). Rathjen, Michael. *[A proof-theoretic characterization of the primitive recursive set functions](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275441)*. J. Symbolic Logic **57** (1992), no. 3, 954–969.

This [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/278033/6085) may be of interest in this respect, illustrating the notions in actual practice, and because of some of the additional references it suggests.

You may also be interested in recursion over admissible sets and, more generally, higher recursion theory, for which an excellent introduction is the book

> [MR1080970 (92a:03062)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1080970). Sacks, Gerald E. **[Higher recursion theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631)**. Perspectives in Mathematical Logic. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990. xvi+344 pp. ISBN: 3-540-19305-7.

For a modern update and recent applications, see

> [MR3381097](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3381097). Chong, Chi Tat; Yu, Liang. **[Recursion theory.
>   Computational aspects of definability](https://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/180947)**. With an interview with Gerald E. Sacks. De Gruyter Series in Logic and its Applications, 8. De Gruyter, Berlin, 2015. xiv+306 pp. ISBN: 978-3-11-027555-1; 978-3-11-038129-0.

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting! I would add a small question. I read about omega consistency, i was thinking about a notion of r.e consistency or predicative consistency, a theory is r.e consistency iff every time it proofs that x is r.e set, it can also give an explicit algorithm to list x. Does anything like this notion exist?

Comment: Or better, if the theory proofs that x with some property exists and it is r.e, the theory could also constructevly show x.

Comment: I don't think I've encountered this notion before. Consider, for instance, a set $x$ such that $x$ is empty if $\mathsf{CH}$ holds and otherwise $x=\mathbb N$. Then $x$ is r.e., but we do not have an explicit witness (an algorithm for it) unless our theory decides $\mathsf{CH}$. (We have a small set of potential witnesses, but that seems trivial.) This example, replacing $\mathsf{CH}$ with any other statement, shows that your theory would have to be complete (so, not the sort of thing one wants in this context, I assume).

Comment: In your example i have an explicit witness for x, even if i cant decide which it is , if empty or N. Indeed x is a costant. But if i say that exist x thath f(x) and x is r.e, but for every r.e x i construct i proof not f(x), it should be different.

Comment: I think there may be something interesting to say there. Why don't you post it as a new question? I suspect some clarification may be requested in the comments, but you will probably get some good answers as well.

Comment: Ok, i will do in next days, i would understand if i write in lateX langue here if it will be converted in symbols or i need a programm, i find it without LateX very limiting. Also i should need a LateX glossary. Is there a way to tag you?

Comment: You could @ me here and let me know.